# Executing a script continuously

Tags: php, cron

I'm currently working on a PHP script that receives emails sent to a specific address and replies according to their content.
It's working great, but now I need it to be executed every 10 seconds.
Here's what I've tried to accomplish that:

- Using a cron job set via cpanel. It works, but even if I use >dev/null 2>&1 I get tons of logs in the root folder of my Web space, even if there are no errors; plus, the minimum interval between two executions is of 1 minute, and I'm looking for something faster
- Using the following code:

  ```
  while(true){
      //my code
      sleep(10);
  }
  ```

But it doesn't seem to work after some minutes.

What method could I use?

Comment: Why does it need to be 10 seconds? Why is 1 minute not fast enough? For that matter, why can't it be immediate as part of some other on demand process?

Comment: @MichaelT thanks for your edit and comment. The reply to emails should be as fast as possible, and I'm afraid that 1 minute is not fast enough for that. Could you make an example of what you mean by "some other on demand process"? If you mean that I should include the code in an other script that is executed per user request, I'm afraid that this method could not be fast enough

Comment: Have some other polling process outside of the server (servers shouldn't be doing log running jobs unless designed for that) that is doing the "pick up the 'I should send an email' message" and then acting on it. Message queues are a classic approach to that (the app just sticks a 'send the email' on the queue, a consumer then pulls it off). The consumer is a process running constantly outside of the server. (and yes, an answer can be built around this comment)

Comment: You can set your script up to be run by the mail server for each incoming email.

Comment: @GrandmasterB thanks for the advice, but unfortunately I don't have access to the mail server

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never???

Making cron execute a PHP script more often than 1 minute is not a possibility or a practical solution you should even explore.

I had a similar project that required fast polling of a target to update a database with new data. The solution for me was to create a PHP Daemon. There are plenty of tutorials about how to write a PHP Daemon so I won't go into the specifics.

Mine was able to run every second to poll an HTTP source. This database was in turn polled every second by a Python script to update a chart on a small screen. Note, the source and polling machine were on the same local network. If you are accessing something further away, you clearly should consider the round trip and processing time when setting your Daemon sleep timer. You can then merely sleep/check for emails/transmit/sleep, etc. within a single command line PHP script rather than needlessly using cron.

Running a Damon also ensures that multiple PHP scripts aren't operating at the same time as can be the case with fast cron job execution. I used a second script to control the startup/status/restart/shutdown of the Daemon PHP script.

I know this isn't an exact answer with examples, but it sounds like all you needed was a recommended direction to take. Based on my experience I believe this will get you where you need to be. As mentioned in the comments there are things to consider about running a polling process on a server, but that is a matter of practice that you can keep in mind as you go.

Comment: I'd argue too that this job is for a daemon. We have a similar problem with an application we're working on. We currently have a cron job running once every two minutes, that runs the risk of contention if two jobs are executing simultaneously. The solution we've decided upon is a daemon, or possibly utilisation of a third party service like AWS Kinesis.